# My distributed app doesn't ask if user want to subscribe to push notifications

Tags: ios, titanium, push-notification

I am developing an app for iOS using Titanium API (SDK 5.0).
This app provides a push notification service, which is successfully tested on dev device.

After publishing with the distribution profile, I realized my app have not asked to users if they accepted the push notifications for this app.

Notice that all devices are on iOS 4.3 or more, I updated my provisioning and distribution profile, I checked certificates for this app, including push notification service.

Here my code for registration:

```
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
    types: [
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
    ],
    success:function(e)
    {
                    //get the device token then send it to server
        var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
                    stockToken(token)
    },
    error:function(e)
    {
        return;
    },
    callback:function(e)
    {
        //when receive a notification
                    winAutres.message_push=e.data.alert;
        tabGroup.setActiveTab(4);
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: You checked your app store distribution profile? (versus adhoc)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know I have to check my app store distribution profile, could you tell me where I can do that ?

Comment: I checked my profile in "Manage Users" but all seems clear.

Comment: I checked my profile in the provisioning portal, and distribution profile is for App Store distribution method.